# Colouring the text in a NSTableView table

Tags: objective-c

I am having no luck colouring the text in a NSTableView table. The delegate methods

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;
```

AND

```
-(NSView*) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
       viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                      row:(NSInteger)row;
```

work fine, but

```
 -(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell1 forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row   
{
          NSLog(@"Fired.");

          if(row==1)
             [cell1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
          else if(row==2)
              [cell1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
          else
              [cell1 setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];     
}
```

does not fire at all. I suspect that I am missing something and help would be appreciated.

Plenty of thanks in advance.

Comment: Coloring what!?  Maybe, the 'colouring the text' statement is clear to you, but not to me.  Is it the text string itself that you want to colorize?  Who knows!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 2 methods are data source methods but the third is a delegate method so you probably haven't connected your controller as the table view `delegate`.

Comment: Thanks Wain for your response. I have got @interface AppDelegate () <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>. Is more required? Thanks,

Comment: You need to set both the delegate and data source properties of the table view (2 different methods).

Comment: Plenty of thanks Wain. I added _myTable2.delegate=self; in awakeFromNib and it worked. _myTable2.dataSource=self; was already there. Thanks again.